# Jenkins github pull request builder for multiple github accounts

Tags: plugins, github, jenkins

We have a Jenkins setup on a server, and are building projects from multiple Github enterprise servers (currently 3 Github enterprise servers). I wanted to use the git pull request builder plugin. However, this plugin only lets us configure one Github account.

Is there a method to include other Github server accounts as well?

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub pull-request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) does mention:

> The first fifty characters in the Description are used to differentiate credentials per job, so again use something semi-descriptive

So as long as your project are built in separate job, you should be able to select in their respective job configuration different credentials.